# Android voice search doesn't recognize Exchange contacts

Tags: sync, gmail, exchange, voice-recognition

So I'm sure this is primarily because the contacts aren't listed in one of the linked gmail accounts. It's killing me because my dad can't use voice commands to call his contacts like he did on his BlackBerry. The only solution I've found so far is to export the exchange contacts to one of the linked gmail accounts. But obviously this must be redone EVERY time he changes something in outlook.

So, is there some way to get voice commands to recognize the Exchange contacts? Or do I have to look for some sort of 3rd party solution that will sync the contacts between the two services?

Also, he doesn't like how the contacts are listed by the person instead of by the company. Any way to change that?

Comment: are you sure you have enabled "Sync Contacts" in the Exchange app? 
They should be reachable after that--

Comment: I'm 90% certain it is. That should be the default setting.

Comment: Ah, but it *isn't*  - 
In the e-mail app, go to settings, the account, and check "Sync Contacts" 
- I would give it a shot to see if this adds the contacts to the voice search, but it would add more contacts than I care to siphon through -- 
HTH!

Comment: Were you able to solve your problem? Any update? What is your Android version?

Comment: To deal with the obscurely picky old dinosaur issue, set up groups. Company 1 > group 1, Company 2 > group 2, etc

Comment: Android's voice search is processed by remote servers, not the phone itself. As a result, the contacts must be in a Google account on the phone in order to be searchable.

Answer (score -1):

Contacts>Settings>Contacts to display>Select all the accounts