# Can I make S-Voice use my Exchange server contacts?

Tags: contacts, exchange, voice-recognition, s-voice

Unfortunately, S-Voice doesn't recognize any of my friend's full names. When I say "Call [*First Name*] [*Last Name*]", it recognizes "Call [*First Name*] [*Some dictionary word that sounds similar to Last Name*]". Obviously, most of my friends' last names cannot be found in any dictionary.

Is there any way to tell S-Voice to somehow "learn" the names from my synced Exchange Server account? I have created a contact named "girlfriend" to be able to call my girlfriend while driving, but I really don't want to add a "dictionary nickname" for every single person I could potentially call.

---

<sub>Related, but unanswered question for some other voice recognition product: [Android voice search doesn't recognize Exchange contacts](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/23456/14204). In case it is relevant: My S-Voice's language is set to German.</sub>